# changing the value of a variable that is being changed inside a jQuery.change() method using checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

hello every one I'm trying to get better at programming and If you could help me that would be appreciated. What im trying to do is set a variable  `var easymode = false;`.. then i would like to check if the easymode option is chosen through a checkbox. im using the jQuery change() method so I could dynamically get a boolean value when the user clicks on and off the the boxes. inside the change method i want to change the value of easymode to true or false. I know I'm not doing it right `if(easymode){
            console.log('true');
        }`
doesnt turn true when easymode is checked.

code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var easymode = false;
    console.log(easymode)

        $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
            if($(this).val() == "easy" && $(this).is(':checked')){
                 easymode = true;
            }
            else if($(this).val() == "easy" && !$(this).is(':checked')){
                // alert('not easy mode');
                 easymode = false;
            }

            if($(this).val() == "hard" && $(this).is(':checked')){
                alert('hard mode')
            }
            else if($(this).val() == "hard" && !$(this).is(':checked')){
                alert('not hard mode');
            }
        })

    if(easymode){
        console.log('true');
    }
    )
});

Easy <input type="checkbox" id="justchange" value="easy"><br>
Hard <input type="checkbox" id="fullprice" value="hard">
<input type="text" id="textbox1">
```

Comment: Your if condition is outside change handler. So the statement will only execute when DOM is loaded. Just move your `if(easymode){` block inside change handler

Comment: that helps alot but something is concerning me I was hoping to get these values outside of the change function because I don't think it's proper to wright alot of the code in the change function is there way to get those values out of the change function or is it ok to write alot of code pertaining to other things that don't have to do with changes of the boxes in the change method. thanks. like I want to do things depending if it is in easymode or not depending if there is a change. I don't know if im expressing my self right.

Comment: Create a function to do whatever operation you want to perform wheather the checkbox is checked or not and then call that function

Comment: ok your saying to call the function in the change method. thanks. I guess the change method is like a wrapper now like $(document).ready(){} whatever just thinking out loud

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

When the user clicks easy, easy mode is on (easymode = true) and hard is unchecked. And when user clicks hard, easymode = false and easy is unchecked.

Of course, you can use radio instead of checkbox and have the checked/unchecked functionality by default.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var easymode = false,
        easy = $('#justchange'),
        hard = $('#fullprice');

    easy.on('click', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            easymode = true;
            hard.prop('checked', false);
        }else{
            easymode = false;
        }
    });

    hard.on('click', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
            easymode = false;
            easy.prop('checked', false);
            alert('hard mode');
        }else{
            alert('not hard mode');

        }
    });
});
```

Also jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xfh32v2o/

Answer (score 0):

You had an error in your code closing an extra bracket. Also, I haven't added that, but you might want to untick the other box when one of them is ticked.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        var easymode = false;
        console.log(easymode);

            $("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function(){
                if($(this).val() == "easy" && $(this).is(':checked')){
                     easymode = true;
                     alert('easy mode');
                }
                else if($(this).val() == "easy" && !$(this).is(':checked')){
                     alert('not easy mode');
                     easymode = false;
                }

                if($(this).val() == "hard" && $(this).is(':checked')){
                    alert('hard mode');
                }
                else if($(this).val() == "hard" && !$(this).is(':checked')){
                    alert('not hard mode');
                }
            });

        if(easymode){
            console.log('true');
        }
    });
```